# UI Path: The Remote Certificate is invalid according to validation procedure

Tags: ssl, smtp, uipath

When i am trying to send mail using SMTP it is throwing error as shown below.

**Source:** Send SMTP Mail Message.

**Message:** The Remote Certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

**Exception Type:** System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException.

I Tried below solutions to resolve.

Disabled Antivirus.
Allowed Less Secure App from my gmail Account.

I have already read below UI Path topics but i didn’t find link to download the trusted certificate.

[The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation](https://forum.uipath.com/t/the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according-to-the-validation/37727)

[Remote Certificate Is Invalid - UiPath](https://forum.uipath.com/t/remote-certificate-is-invalid-uipath/28258)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify the link below. First, we need to disable antivirus.

https://forum.uipath.com/t/the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according-to-the-validation/37727/3

Answer (score 0):

Windows maintains its trusted CAs in a Certification Directory, and you can read more about that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/seccertenroll/about-certificate-directory). The server's certificate is either self-signed, or the certifying authority is not part of your Certification Directory (resolving the whole chain of trust).

Since you mentioned Gmail - that's quite unusual since Google Trust Services is trusted by Global Sign, and Global Sign usually is part of the CD. Here's an example of the required certificate for Gmail (SMTP via port 465):

```
lynxvvv:~ wolfgangradl$ openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:465 -showcerts
CONNECTED(00000006)
depth=2 OU = GlobalSign Root CA - R2, O = GlobalSign, CN = GlobalSign
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Google Trust Services, CN = Google Internet Authority G3
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = California, L = Mountain View, O = Google LLC, CN = smtp.gmail.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google LLC/CN=smtp.gmail.com
   i:/C=US/O=Google Trust Services/CN=Google Internet Authority G3
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEgjCCA2qgAwIBAgIII4WYR6PlomgwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwVDELMAkGA1UE
(...)
```

You can always download and install a custom certificate into the store, [here's an excellent article from Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/97201/how-to-save-a-remote-server-ssl-certificate-locally-as-a-file). If we're talking about Gmail, then you could get them from [Google directly](https://pki.google.com/) as well.